# Detect when a player uses a totem of undying

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am currently making a plugin and would like to give the player some potion effects such as slowness when they use a totem of undying.

This is what I've tried so far. It runs when an entity dies without a totem, but when an entity dies with a totem, it will send the message "Totem has been Used" but will not give the effects.

```
@EventHandler
public void OnUseTotem(EntityResurrectEvent event)
{
        Bukkit.getLogger().info("TOTEM USED");
        event.getEntity().sendMessage("TOTEM HAS BEEN USED");

        Entity entity = event.getEntity();

        entity.sendMessage("Activate");
        entity.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.SLOW, 200,10),true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of issue appear because the entity isn't ready yet to respawn (as you can cancel event for example. It's like "pre" event.

And as when you're dead/respawning, you can't have potion effect, you don't have one)

To fix this, you can apply this but few times after thanks to [`BukkitScheduler`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitScheduler.html) :

```java
@EventHandler
public void OnUseTotem(EntityResurrectEvent event) {
      Bukkit.getLogger().info("TOTEM USED");
      Entity entity = event.getEntity();

      entity.sendMessage("TOTEM HAS BEEN USED");
      entity.sendMessage("Activate");
      Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(myPlugin, () -> {
          entity.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.SLOW, 200,10),true);
      }, 1);
}
```

Wait 1 tick should be enough. You can set "0", it will just wait for next tick. You can set more to be sure (as 20 tick, so 1 second)